# JavaMail API keeps saying it cannot connect. CAS Array & Exchange

Tags: java, connection, jakarta-mail

Here is what I have so far. I am trying to send an email in Outlook and embed that functionality into my application.

```
String to = "me@mine.com";
String from = "you@yours";
String host = "casarray.ex2.specificallygeneral.net";
final String username = "user@doamin.com";
final String password = "password";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", "user@domain.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.password", "password");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

    Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {
      protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
          return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
      }
    };

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, authenticator);      

    try {
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(to)};
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
        msg.setSubject("Test");
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        msg.setText("This API works");
        Transport transport = session.getTransport();
        transport.connect(username, password);
        transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
        Transport.send(msg);
        transport.sendMessage(msg, address);
        if (transport == null) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Mail carrier was shot. Sorry.");
        }

        }   
    catch (MessagingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AAIApplication.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

And here is what I get each time:

`com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port:       casarray.ex2.secureserver.net, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1961)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:345)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:226)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
    at AAIworkordertracker.AAIApplication.addToTrackerbtnActionPerformed(AAIApplication.java:412)
    at AAIworkordertracker.AAIApplication.access$1200(AAIApplication.java:27)
    at AAIworkordertracker.AAIApplication$13.actionPerformed(AAIApplication.java:171)
    at java.awt.Button.processActionEvent(Button.java:409)
    at java.awt.Button.processEvent(Button.java:377)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at       java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:297)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:229)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1927)
    ... 29 more`

If someone could give me a hand on this and let me know what I am doing wrong. It looks perfectly to me, so, I am assuming that the issues lies with the Exchange server. What do you think?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Couldn't connect to host, port" could be caused by wrong host name, wrong port, a blocking firewall (on the server, on gateways, even on your own machine), network failure, server downtime, etc. You might want to find out if you can connect/"talk" to the mail server using telnet from the command line. See also http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug

Note: On Windows 7, you might need to install telnet first. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/978779

Comment: I have Outlook opened on the computer that I am developing with. So that eliminates connectivity issues and downtime. Since I am connected to the Exchange server with the same credentials that I want to use in the Java app, will the server reject a second connection even if the credentials are good? I think that it is probably that or maybe I have an incorrect port. Is there a way to find out the correct port without contacting the server maintainer? Doing this as an "above-and-beyond" project for work. Don't want to let them know until it's done and working, ya know?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know enough about Exchange Server and Outlook to be of much more help. But it is probably not an authentication but a connection problem and you would have to find out the host/port somehow. Maybe you can extract SMTP/IMAP configuration from Outlook. Note that SMTP is not mentioned on the following page [Ports used by Exchange Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278339/EN-US) - so maybe it is not even available by default.

Comment: Outlook normally uses the Microsoft proprietary protocol to connect to Exchange.  It's possible SMTP isn't even enabled, or that only SMTP-over-SSL is enabled; try the "smtps" protocol.  Also, note that there's a bunch of mistakes in your code, including some of [these](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Comment: @BillShannon you are right about the mistakes. I've learned quite a bit more about the API recently and I picked that garbage outta my code last night.